# How to use res.render to send data every time a page is routed to?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server, pug

I had posted a question earlier but I see that I had focused on the wrong issue as I thought my problem was on the database side but instead the problem seems to be with "res.render" as it is getting the correct data from the database it just isn't being sent to my front end after the first call. And I have seen a question earlier on stack overflow saying to get around this send a full array instead and do the iterating on the client side but that solution will not work for me because I am ensuring that multiple people can be using the tool at the same time which is why I am use a lock in my sql query to ensure that this process is being done one at a time and not replicating data.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  connection.query("LOCK TABLE data.train_data WRITE; SELECT * FROM data.train_data LIMIT 1; DELETE FROM data.train_data LIMIT 1; UNLOCK TABLES;",(err,rows) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error selecting tweets from Database...');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Successfully received tweets from database');
     res.render('index', {
       title: 'Tweet Labeler',
       data: rows[1]
     });
  });
```

The res.render block here is where I am having trouble because the first time I know it is correctly sending the data but every time after it doesn't seem to be sending it properly. And I believe it is either because I am using this wrong or there is something wrong with my javascript function below where maybe I need to ensure that like the data that is being refreshed... and honestly I am not completely sure how the javascript knows that the JSON.stringify(data) refers to the data that is being sent by res.render? So maybe that could also be an issue:

```
          script.
            var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
            function nextItem() {
              data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
              console.log("The new data is:");
              console.log(data[0]);
              if (data){
                //- document.getElementById("label").innerHTML= "Current Tweet ID: " + curIndex
                document.getElementById("tweetText").innerHTML = data[0].tweet
              }
             }
             function relClick(){
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               var newData = {'tweet':data[0].tweet,'relevant':1};
               var jsonData = JSON.stringify(newData);
               xhr.open("POST","/",true);
               xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
               xhr.send(jsonData);
               console.log("Clicked Relevant");
               xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhr.open("GET","/",true);
               xhr.send();
               nextItem();
             }
             function irrClick(){
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               var newData = {'tweet':data[0].tweet,'relevant':0};
               var jsonData = JSON.stringify(newData);
               xhr.open("POST","/",true);
               xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
               xhr.send(jsonData);
               console.log(jsonData);
               console.log("Clicked Irrelevant")
               nextItem();
             }
             rel.addEventListener('click',relClick);
             irr.addEventListener('click',irrClick);
             next.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
```

Basically I know it is working correctly but something is just wrong with the data because in my console where I am hosting the server I am printing out the results of the query and it is correct but when I print them out in my browser console it is the same row every time from when the page initially opened so I know that isn't being updated. NOTE* I did this using PUG for the templating.

I even tried using an if statement to use send if it isn't the first time instead of render but it still doesn't work...

Thank you so much to everyone taking the time to help me I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen syntax " var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)} "

My most familiar equivalent would be var data = !(JSON.stringify(data))

Or maybe you could try to pass the data to nextItem() when you call it nextItem(newData)

See what does:

```
var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
console.log(data)
```

say?

Also it is not visible what happens at the API when you send the xhr.send(). Try to console.log() the request on the api side. For the post request.

Comment: That syntax is for pug basically lets it know that you are using the server side variable names I think? And I can't access the "newData" in anything on the frontend... so can't do that solution yet